# Maximal size of independent generator set in simple group

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that for every integer $k$, exists $n$, such that for every finite, not Abelian simple group $G$ 
 with maximal size of independent generator set less than $k$, then $|G|<n$.

Independent generator set $S$ is any set of elements in group $G$ wich generate $G$, but every smaller subset of $S$ don't generate $G$.

We prove that such $n=1$ exists if $k=2$. Let given finite, not Abelian simple group $G$ 
 with maximal size of independent generator set $\leq 2$. From Feit-Thompson Theorem $\exists x\in G: x^2=e$, $G$ is simple, so $\langle\{\cup_{g\in G}gxg^{-1}\}\rangle =G$ and so $\exists x'\in G: x'^2 = e, G = \langle x,x'\rangle$, but then $\langle xx'\rangle\lhd G$, so $G = \langle xx'\rangle$ is Abelian. $\Box$

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a worse butchering of quantifier notation.

Comment: I am sorry for bad English

Comment: The English is fine, lol. You must just be used to a different notation than I am; It's the fact that you say $\forall X \subseteq G: \langle X \rangle = G ...$ when you mean $\forall X \subseteq G$ *such that* $\langle X \rangle = G ...$. To me a colon should indicate everything that goes *after* any conditions made on the object being quantified; for you the separation is made by a comma. The difference doesn't matter for existential quantifiers, but it matters for the universal quantifier $\forall$.

Comment: Your question could be improved by explaining how you get the case $k=2$.

Comment: This problem is about maximal length of independent generator set in simple groups.

Comment: I edited this post

Comment: Can you say what you mean by an "independent generator set" of a group? BTW, every finite simple group can be generated by two elements, one of which can be an element of order $2$.

Comment: Also, sets don't have lengths. You can talk about the size or the cardinality of a set, but not its length. Sequences have lengths.

Comment: It is known that minimal size of independent generator set in simple not Abelian groups is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "independent generating sets" are often called "irredundant generating sets".

The answer to the question is no. It is proved in

J. Whiston, J. and J. Saxl, On the maximal size of independent generating sets of PSL2 (q), J. Algebra 258 (2002) 651-657

that the maximal size of an irredundant generating set of the simple group ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$ is at most $4$ for all primes $p$, so if you take $k=4$ then there is no upper bound on $|G|$.

In fact if $p \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$ and $p \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod {10}$, then the maximal size is $3$, so there is also no upper bound with $k=3$.