# Finding large irredundant generator sets for a finite noncommutative group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Suppose $G$ is a finite noncommutative group. 
A set $\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ of elements of $G$ is called irredundant if none of its elements is contained in the subgroup generated by the rest of elements (hope I properly use an already defined notion). Of course such a set is maximal if it can not be further extended i.e. it generates $G$ itself.
I am looking for such maximal irredundant sets of generators of largest possible size $n$. As $G$ is finite, the existence of such sets is guaranteed.

From a theoretical point of view my question is then: what is known about the construction of such sets?
From an application point of view actually I am interested in effective algorithmic computations for $G$, using GAP. As an example, in my case, think of the semidirect product of $S_6$ with $Z^6$, defined as a permutation group in GAP. In the case it is not known an algorithm to compute a largest maximal irredundant set of generators, I am interested in any algorithmic way of computing such maximal irredundant sets of generators. Of course I am looking for a set of largest size.

Thanks for any hint and advise.

Comment: Such sets are often called *independent* generating sets. If you search for that, you will find some results. For example the largest size is $n-1$ for $S_n$.An earlier question on this topic was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004210 From an algorithmic viewpoint I would expect the problem to be very hard. It is very easy to check whether a given set of generators is irredundant, but how could you establish purely computationally that the set had maximal size?

Comment: By the way, I don't understand your example. What is $Z^6$? "defined as a permutation group in GAP" is a strange way to define a group!

Comment: Sorry @Derek Holt, I would say $Z_2^6$.

Comment: Thanks @Derek Holt for the comments. I felt the earlier question on this topic useless to me. I felt also the sharp question (maximal size) could be hard from algorithmic viewpoint. This is why I said I would be happy to have an algorithm to compute several maximal independent generating sets. I can imagine well that such an algorithm can be set up using the many series of the group's subgroups. I also suspect that the answer can be hidden in the structure (graph) of the group's subgroup lattice, but I have no clue how.

Comment: There are several different semidirect products of $Z_2^6$ by $S_6$, but I am guessing that you are talking about the extension by the permutation module: i.e. $Z_2 \wr S_6$. In that case, assuming that the largest size of an irredundant generating set for $S_6$ is $5$, the largest size for the semidirect product in question must be $6$.

Comment: Your guess is correct @Derek Holt. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult in general, but can often be computed.  Dan Collins's [undergrad thesis](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dcollins/CornellThesis.pdf) has some discussion of the question, e.g. see page 8.  (He calls the largest size of an irredundant generating set $\overline r$; I'm more accustomed to calling it $m$.)  One useful computational tool is the following result, which appears in some unpublished notes of Collins:

**Lemma**:  if $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $N$ is abelian, then $m(G) = m(G/N)$ if $N \leq \Phi(G)$, and $m(G) = m(G/N) + 1$ otherwise.  (Here, $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup.  The first case is a standard fact and doesn't require minimality of $N$.)

This in particular allows one to recursively compute $m(G)$ for any finite solvable $G$, since a minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group is necessarily abelian.  In Keith Dennis's 2013 REU program at Cornell, Atticus Christensen and I (also unpublished) observed that this lemma can also be used to calculate $m(G)$ where $G$ is the wreath product $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \wr S_n$, by reducing to Whiston's theorem that $m(S_n) = n-1$.  Namely, $m(G)$ is $n$ if $n$ is even, and $n+1$ if $n$ is odd.  The proof follows without too much difficulty from writing down all the normal subgroups contained in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$ (i.e. the $S_n$-invariant subspaces of $(\mathbb F_2)^n$) and checking which ones are contained in the Frattini subgroup.

To get an explicit irredundant generating set of $G = (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \wr S_6$ of size 6, you can take a size-5 irredundant generating set of (your favorite embedding of) $S_6 < G$, and append to it any element of $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^6 < G$ with an odd number of 1's.

Comment: Thank you @Ravi Fernando for the answer. For the moment these are  basically just enough information for the problem I considered.